# Behaviour of "PERFORM Paragraph THRU paragraph-exit UNTIL end"

Tags: cobol, mainframe

i would like to know the behaviour of this statements bellow:

```
SET NOK TO TRUE
PERFORM PARAGRAPHE-1 THRU PARAGRAPHE-2 UNTIL NOK
```

Is paragraphs from PARAGRAPHE-1 until PARAGRAPHE-2 are executed or no ?

Answer (score 4):

It will not be executed, because exit evaluation happens before executing the perform statements, by default.

If you want to test the condition after the execution, you need to do it explicitly, like this.

```
PERFORM PARAGRAPHE-1 THRU PARAGRAPHE-2 WITH TEST AFTER UNTIL NOK
```